# Yii2 add condition in the last one of chain relations

Tags: database, yii2

Right now I have:

```
$products = Product::findAll([1,2,3,4]);
foreach ($products as $product){
    $text = $product->part->type->texts;
}
```

This returns the related records from `Texts` table.

But I need to have only 1 record from it, and to do that I need to have one more condition in the last join `type->texts`, which is not defined in the model. It's dynamic session variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want modify the last relation query to have additional condition and return one record instead of many, simply change last relation call like so:

```
$text = $product->part->type->getTexts()->andWhere(...)->one();
```

Direct relation method call returns `yii\db\ActiveQuery` instance so you can modify conditions how you want.

If you want to use modified relation in more than just one place, create separate method for that:

```
/**
 * @return yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getDynamicText()
{
    // Insert link from texts relation similar as in hasMany() and additional condition in andWhere()
    return $this->hasOne(...)->andWhere(...);
}
```

And then use it:

```
$text = $product->part->type->dynamicText;
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, [scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#scopes) would be a handy solution, especially if you're going to use complicated conditions.

**1.** Start by creating a model that extends `ActiveQuery` with a method that will be used to add conditions to your query, for example `active = 1`:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class TextQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
    public function active($state = 1)
    {
        $this->andWhere(['active' => $state]); // or any other condition
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**2.** Override the `find()` method in your `Text` model:

```
public static function find()
{
    return new \app\models\TextQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

**3.** Add a method in your `Type` model that retrieves your relational data via the newly made scope:

```
public function getActiveText()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Text::className(), ['type_id' => 'id'])->active();
}
```

Finally, use it as follows:

```
$text = $product->part->type->activeText;
```

The docs are pretty clear on this, check 'em out.